# mod-mono-server4 error on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apache2, 14.04, mono

I installed ubuntu 14.04 a few days ago and as i am a .net developer i tried the latest      mono available for ubuntu that is 3.2.8 , and just after i installed mod-mono-server4 it crashed the apache server,and every time i restarted my apache server mod-mono-server4 would crash it that was a bug which i found reported below.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xsp/+bug/1293481

I fixed this bug on my own system and reported the fix on the bug page given above , now  their is another problem , every time i restart my computer it gives me a System.Web.HttpException which i know is because of permissions on the web application root i set the proper permissions and restarted apache the problem was gone and again if now i restart my computer the problem comes again, what could be the reason what i am missing ?

This is not something that a production environment will need as they do not restart their systems, but i just wanted to know what is wrong with it , and as it seems i am not alone facing this problem the ubuntu's own web site is facing this too go to the following page and see the same exception at the right side

http://www.ubuntu.com/tv

they will need to restart their apache server but if anyone knows a better way to fix this, that will be great

Comment: update http://www.ubuntu.com/tv websites's exception is gone now, i think they have fixed the bug. But where is the patch?